# Build Definition Task File Pattern

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

For a Visual Studio Team Services Build Definition step **Build Solution (Visual Studio Build)**, how would one structure a pattern to both include and exclude files/folders. For example, to include all `.sln` files I'm able to use `**\*.sln` and to exclude node_modules I could us `!node_modules`. How could I combine this within the **Solution** field of the Build Solution edit UI?

`**\*.sln,!node_modules` returns an invalid pattern error. Is there a separator that I can use to specify multiple glob patterns?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: What's the result with my solution? It is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this value instead:

```
**\*.sln;-:**\node_modules\**
```